# Suspicious 3-way repeated measures ANOVA results

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, matlab

I'm getting weird results using the fitrm and ranova functions in Matlab. I've asked a similar question in the [Matlab forums](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/173277-problem-with-repeated-measures-anova-within-subject-models%22matlab%20forums%22).

The table below is part of the results for a 3-way repeated measures ANOVA with 9 subjects, 3 between-subject factors (Age, Gender, Task Order), and 36 responses from 3 within-subject factors (Time, Task, Side).

[image: Part of 3-way RM ANOVA Results Table]

This is my first time with ANOVAs but from what I've read, these results seem dubious. The degrees of freedom (DF) seem low; all the GG and HF sphericity estimates are the same as the lower bound (LB); and none of the results (most of which aren't in the picture) are significant except for those involving (Intercept).

Is this a valid result, or have I done something wrong?

Also, does anybody know what the (Intercept) variable means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a small sample size and few levels of your independent variables, so all the df's will be small.  The lack of statistical significance may be due to your small N.  Did you plot the data to try to understand your findings?  If so, what did you find?

Comment: You're right about the sample size, I did more reading and realised it's not large enough to be any use for between-subject factors. Also I found out that I hadn't changed my age variable to categorical, which affects the DF. Thanks!